# How to interpret results of LinearDiscriminantAnalysis?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm interested in understanding what "features" are most impactful in a multi-class classification.

I've done this with PCA and that appears to allow me to inspect the directional variance in each feature per component via the `components_ vector`.

I'm struggling to interrogate the results of LDA as to understanding which features are part of each component and what their impact is...

Any suggestions on what elements of the LDA object after `fit_transform` can be used to gain feature specific insights per component?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-pca-vs-lda-py) is an answer from the documentation of `sklearn` itself.

> > Principal Component Analysis (PCA) applied to this data identifies the combination of attributes (principal components, or directions in the feature space) that account for the most variance in the data. Here we plot the different samples on the 2 first principal components.
> >
> > Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) tries to identify attributes that account for the most variance between classes. In particular, LDA, in contrast to PCA, is a supervised method, using known class labels.

Comment: This is why I'm attempting to use LDA to understand the drivers between classes.  What I'm after is what "attributes" account for the variance...